# Get error from DLL invoke parameter pass at c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pinvoke

**`DLLENTRY int     CCON    mfScan                  (int, int, int, char *, int *);`**

```
[DllImport("mflib.dll")]
public static extern int mfScan(int mode, int font, int timeout, string ret_codeline, int ret_maxchars);
```

I get the below error with this code. It points to test. What can i do ?

```
 string test = string.Empty;
 int retval = mfScan(32, 2, 5000, test, 100);
```

**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
[DllImport("mflib.dll")]
public static extern int mfScan(int mode, int font, int timeout, StringBuilder ret_codeline, out int ret_maxchars);
```

Please note the `StringBuilder` instead of string, additionally to the `out int ret_maxchars`.
Then ensure the calling convention is correct.

Comment: I want accept your answer too but GSerg was first. Thank you.

Comment: @Orhan Cinar if it works without the StringBuilder you properly accepted the other one :)

Comment: With the string version i cant get the codeline. Must init the string length.

Answer (score 3):

Should be `out int ret_maxchars`.

You should also consider adding `CharSet` to the `DllImport`.